# usage of VHDL generics

Tags: generics, vhdl

I'm learning VHDL and I haven't understood yet how to properly use generics. Let's assume that I need to describe different multiplexers using a 2:1 MUX with variable number of bits. Let's call this parameter p.
This is an example code (this code doesn't matter that much in this context tbh )

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mux2to1_gen is
generic ( p : POSITIVE := 1 );    
port ( 
       x,y : in std_logic_vector ( p-1 downto 0 );  
       s : in std_logic;    
       m : out std_logic_vector ( p-1 downto 0 )
);
end mux2to1_gen;


architecture logic of mux2to1_gen is
     signal s_vector : std_logic_vector ( p-1 downto 0 );   
begin
     s_vector <= ( others => s ); 
     m <= (NOT (s_vector) AND x) OR (s_vector AND y);   
end architecture;
```

I'd like to use this code to easily create a 2:1 8bit MUX, i.e. p = 8 or maybe a 5:1 MUX using four 2:1 MUX on 1 bit. So basically, I want to create another file and easily use this code only declaring the value of p in the first case and just something more in the second one. How do I do that?

Comment: I hope you realize that nobody in real HDL design uses MUXes that way. That is only done in education. In real design you just use an if statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the magic happens in the instance (component or entity).    Assuming you have already done a component declaration, at the place where you want to create your different size multiplexors:

```
-- Create 8:1 Mux
Mux8_1 : mux2to1_gen 
  generic map (p => 8 )
  port map (x => A8, y => B8, s => Mux8Sel, m => MuxOut8) ; 

-- Create 5:1 Mux
Mux5_1 : mux2to1_gen 
  generic map (p => 5 )
  port map (x => X5, y => Y5, s => Mux5Sel, m => MuxOut5) ;
```

The above used the generally preferred method of named association.  You can also positionally associate the ports as shown below, however, this makes designs harder to maintain and review.  Keep in mind, most code is written by one person, but reviewed by numerous (including the person who does the next revision), so while named association increases the effort of design capture, it decreases the overall effort.

```
-- Create 8:1 Mux
Mux8_1 : mux2to1_gen 
  generic map (8 )
  port map (A8, B8, Mux8Sel, MuxOut8) ;
```

Comment: so basically, I still need to manually redefine the port even if it depends upon p and I want no more inputs/outputs ?

Comment: Redefine is not the right word. You do need to individually "connect" all ports in the component/entity instantiation even if they don't depend on the generic.

Comment: Expanding on @Plebala thoughts.   Entity ports are like pins on a chip.  The names A8, B8, Mux8Sel, and MuxOut8 are the wires on the board that connect the chip to other things.